# mariadb sql select distinct values from json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, mariadb, distinct

The database version
**mariadb 10.3.16**
I have a JSON of objects labels: an array of strings

So when I am querying just the labels value, I have the result

```
["label1", "label7"]
["label2", "labeltest"]
["label1", "labeltest"]
```

How can I extract only distinct values from here?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [recursive CTEs](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/recursive-common-table-expressions-overview/) and [JSON functions](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-functions/) to extract the label values.

Here's an example query that extracts the unique values from JSON arrays in a table:

```
WITH RECURSIVE labels AS (
  SELECT 0 AS depth, JSON_VALUE(data, CONCAT('$[', 0, ']')) AS data
    FROM t1
    WHERE JSON_LENGTH(t1.data) > 0
  UNION
  SELECT l.depth + 1, JSON_VALUE(t1.data, CONCAT('$[', l.depth + 1, ']')) AS data
    FROM t1, labels as l
    WHERE JSON_LENGTH(t1.data) - 1 > l.depth
)
SELECT data FROM labels;
```